# Does aufs ( or any other OverlayFS alternative ) support direct access to lower branches?

Tags: linux, overlay, aufs

Is there any union-type filesystem that can handle online edits to lower branches?

Use-case: OS configuration management

I wish to store my main OS in lowest dir. This dir should be the unconfigured OS. Let's call the dir `OSdir`. Furthermore I need a place to store `etc` changes, so above `OSdir` I'd put a `confdir`.  Lastly `workdir` above all of them. I'd like to be able to merge **some** changes from `workdir` to `confdir`. I do **not** want to reboot and boot into another system, just so I can edit some files.

With this setup, I could:

- See exactly which files have changed from the unconfigured system state
- Rapidly recover from a fatal system failure (assuming backup of `confdir` survived)

I know that OverlayFS does not support this, because it is explicitly mentioned in the docs, however I failed to find info on the others.

Nevertheless: **Is there any union-type filesystem that can handle online edits to lower branches?**

Comment: I'd also like to add, *YES* I could just store config files in the `workdir` however workdir is going to be filled with a lot of runtime generated data and I wish to separate those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does! It's called "UDBA" (Users Direct Branch Access) and is described over here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/aufs.5.html